# How do I map a command to a file path

Tags: command-line, executable, paths

I am new to Linux. I have read the basic docs.

I have just installed Filezilla. I first tried `apt-get` but the repository does not appear to be up to date. I then downloaded it from the Filezilla web site, unzipped, and I am now able to use the program from unity.

I am trying to understand the command line though... if I type:

```
Desktop/Filezilla/bin/filezilla
```

The program opens but throws a bunch of errors in the console:

```
(filezilla:2767): Gtk-Critical **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertation 'width >= -1' failed
```

I would like to know how to "map" the location of the executable to a simple command like:

```
$filezilla
```

And also if there is a reason for the errors when I type in the path directly. Sorry if I am missing something easy but thanks for helping a newbie :)

Comment: The standard repo version was too old or something? How about this PPA https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/programs-ppa  with version 3.10.1.1-0u0~ppa1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Linux and Ubuntu.

The messages you see in the command line are not to worry about. They are related to the FileZilla GUI and are more warnings than anything else; if the programme runs as expected leave it be.

The easiest way to execute Filezilla from the command line as you ask is by creating an [alias](http://www.linfo.org/alias.html). Type the following command:

```
alias filezilla='~/Desktop/Filezilla/bin/filezilla'
```

To make the alias permanent you must add it to the `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
echo "alias filezilla='~/Desktop/Filezilla/bin/filezilla'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

After that you can simply type `filezilla` to execute the programme.

Better still is to make Unity awere that FileZilla is installed. To do so you need to create a file named `filezilla.desktop` in the `~/.local/share/applications` folder. The contents of this file could look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=FileZilla
Icon=<path/to/fillezilla/icon>
Exec=/home/<user>/Desktop/Filezilla/bin/filezilla
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
Comment=
```

Where you should replace `<path/to/fillezilla/icon>` for a path to the FileZilla icon and `<user>`for your user name. After creating this file, you need to log out and log on again for the FileZilla element to appear in the Lens.

Comment: You should rather use a double chevron `>>` to not override an existing `.bash_aliases` but append the new line.

Comment: Thanks man thats a great help. I am using linux as much as possible and there is a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

You could add `Desktop/Filezilla/bin/filezilla` to you bash search path (where bash looks when you try to run a program). The command to do this is `export`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360889/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-ubuntu) and [this article](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm) have more information about adding to the search path. I do not know how to solve the error though.